# MATLAB solve() returns array for linear equation

Tags: matlab, logical-operators, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I have the following equation in MATLAB:
`eqn1 = (1-t)*x1 + t*x2 == x;` where `x1,y1 = <some_constant_value>`
I am solving the equation as:
`t1 = double(solve(subs(eqn1,x,min(x_arr(i,:))),t));` and doing a comparison as:

```
if(t1 >= 0 & t1 <= 1)
    crossing = 1;
    return
end
```

However, from time to time, I get the following error:
**Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values.**
From what I found out on other forums/answers, this is because `&&` and `||` is not capable of handling arrays and hence, the error. But, considering I am solving a linear equation, why is MATLAB returning an array?

**EDIT**
My apologies, I forgot to give the initialization for the variables:
`syms x y t`
`x1` as `double`
`x2` as `double`
`y1` as `double`
`y2` as `double`
`x_arr` as `double`
`y_arr` as `double`

Comment: How do you initialize x1 and y1 and what does solve return? Maybe no solution is returned?

Comment: please post the actual code, something we can test.

Comment: This is still not enough info for us to reproduce the problem (see [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If I had to guess, perhaps `solve` found multiple solutions? Maybe you can modify your `if` test to use `all` and `any` functions depending on your application...

Comment: @Amro this is a self-sufficient function and runs independent of the rest of the code. The actual code is far too large to reproduce here, so I thought this would be enough.  
I thank you for your time and effort in trying to solve this problem.

Comment: @Amro my only question was that why would `solve` return multiple solutions for a linear equation of one variable? Perhaps you could shed some light on that?

Comment: that was just a wild guess, we didn't have much to go on.. The other possibility is that your actual code has a bug not depicted in your stripped-down example. Say are you using `&` or `&&` in the original if condition?

Comment: Since I want to check if `t` lies between `0` and `1`, I am using `&&`. But if I change it to `&`, I don't get the error. This confirms the fact that `solve` returns a vector, which is the confusing part.

Comment: well you can always debug it by placing a breakpoint at that line and know for sure :) We don't have the full code, so only you can do it. MATLAB also has an option to break on error `dbstop if error` that comes in handy to debug errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working in a *hacky* manner by splitting the `if` conditions as:

```
if(t1 >= 0)
    if(t1 <= 1)
        crossing = 1;
        return
    end
end
```